# Why is the Hecke algebra commutative

Tags: representation-theory

I am following some course notes about local representation theory. It introduces the Hecke algebra of $G=GL_n(F)$ for a non-Archimedean local field F as the space of compactly supported, bi-$K$-invariant functions on $G$, considered as an algebra under convolution.

I would like to show that this Hecke algebra is commutative. It advises to "consider the transpose map and show that it induces a map on the Hecke algebra which is both an involution and an anti-involution". However I do not see what map to consider: is it $f(g) \mapsto f({}^t g)$? (which is still $K$-invariant)

Comment: I am not familiar with the setting, but if you have an algebra $A$, and a mapping $s:A\to A$ such that 1) $s$ is an involution, i.e. $s^{-1}=s$, 2) $s$ is a ring homomorphism, $s(ab)=s(a)s(b)$ for all $a,b\in A$, and 3) $s$ is an antihomomorphism, $s(ab)=s(b)s(a)$ for all $a,b\in A$, then it does follow that $A$ must be commutative. Don't know if this fits here.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for your answer, I did understand this point, and indeed this should lead to the conclusion. However, I do not see which map $s$ we are considering in this case...

Comment: Does the one you suggested work? I don't know what $K$-invariant refers to this time, but judging from similar situations elsewhere (that I'm more familiar with) it looks like a natural thing to try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We follow Exe 5.14 of a GTM preprint by Getz and Hahn. What to be considered is indeed $f\mapsto f({}^t*)=:f^\dagger$. We show this is an anti-homomorphism. First, for $f\in C_c^\infty (G)$, we have
$$
\int f(g)dg = \int f({}^tg^{-1})dg.
$$
This is because sending $f$ to the RHS of the above is left invariant, and because the above is true for $f = \mathbf 1_{GL_n(\mathcal O_F)}$.

By the above, for $f_1, f_2\in C_c^\infty (G)$ and $g\in GL_n(F)$, we have
$$
(f_1*f_2)({}^tg)=\int f_1(h)f_2(h^{-1}{}^tg)dh = \int f_1({}^th^{-1})f_2({}^th{}^tg)dh = \int f_1({}^tg{}^th^{-1})f_2({}^th)dh = (f_2^\dagger*f_1^\dagger)(g).
$$

In place of proving that $\dagger$ is a homomorphism on $C_c^\infty(GL_n(F)//GL_n(\mathcal O_F))$, we show that $\dagger$ is the identity here. Fixing a uniformizer $\pi\in\mathcal O_F$, notice
$$
GL_n(F) = \bigcup_{a_1\geqq a_2\geqq\dots a_n} GL_n(\mathcal O_F)\mathrm{diag}(\pi^{a_1},\dots, \pi^{a_n})GL_n(\mathcal O_F).
$$
This is because for an arbitrary $A\in GL_n(F)$, we can arrange that $A_{11}$ has the largest absolute value by the multiplication of elementary matrices on both sides, conduct the Gaussian elimination with respect to $A_{11}$, and then continue.

Now, $\dagger$ is the identity on $C_c^\infty(GL_n(F)//GL_n(\mathcal O_F))$ since the same is true on the set of diagonal matrices.

Comment: Yes, this is the classic argument, perhaps attributable to Gelfand and Kazhdan. Yes, it uses something non-trivial about the group! Nevertheless, quasi-amazingly, an analogous fact holds for all the reductive $p$-adic groups I know (or maybe "care about" :) so it turns out to be a generally useful argument.